# How to read the maximum of series values from the entire yesterday?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Here's my own VWAP indicator.
[image: VWAP Indicator]
**I would like to know the max width of its Bands, but from yesterday, to use the data continuously today.**

I tried to play with `request.security()` and `math.max()` and `ta.highest()` but couldn't manage to achieve anything useful.

What I should know exactly, is the maximum value of `upperBandValue - vwapValue` from yesterday. I have put it into a 'VwapBandWidth' series variable but then lost the challenge, when trying to retrieve its maximum value, not to mention from yesterday.

Any idea? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Found it out myself. The code requires the `isNewPeriod` Boolean code segment from the original VWAP indicator.

```
Something = <calculated_series> //We watch its maximum value.

var float MaxSomething_Today = 0
var float MaxSomething_Yesterday = 0

if Something > MaxSomething_Today
    MaxSomething_Today := Something

if isNewPeriod
    MaxSomething_Yesterday := MaxSomething_Today
    MaxSomething_Today := 0
```